# Returns None instead of False

Tags: python, function, return

So I'm working on a question on CodingBat, a website that provides JS and Python practice problems. I've encountered a unexpected output. Btw here's the link to the question: https://codingbat.com/prob/p135815 . In theory my code should return False but it returns none when I put print(squirrel_play(50, False))

Code:

```
def squirrel_play(temp, is_summer):
if is_summer:
    if temp <= 100:
        if temp >= 60:
            return True
    elif temp <= 60:
        return False
    elif temp >= 100:
        return False
if not is_summer:
    if temp <= 90:
        if temp >= 60:
            return True
    elif temp >= 90: 
        return False
    elif temp <= 60:
        return False
```

when I run that with print(squirrel_play(50, False)), I get None (I should get False)
Why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your parameter of is_summer of False, you're in the 2nd conditional block:

```py
if not is_summer:
    if temp <= 90:
        if temp >= 60:
            return True
    elif temp >= 90: 
        return False
    elif temp <= 60:
        return False
```

Then follow this block:

- is the temp less than 90? yes. so now we're in this block:

```py
if temp <= 90:
  if temp >= 60:
    return True
```

What is happening here is that you never get to the `elif temp <= 60` because you are in the first conditional instead. You could only ever get to the elif below if you didn't satisfy the first condition.

At the end of this `if temp <= 90` block the entire conditional chain ends and your function returns the default value of `None` because you didn't provide another return value.

You can maybe more clearly see this by making the entire code read:

```py
def squirrel_play(temp, is_summer):
if is_summer:
    if temp <= 100:
        if temp >= 60:
            return True
    elif temp <= 60:
        return False
    elif temp >= 100:
        return False
if not is_summer:
    if temp <= 90:
        if temp >= 60:
            return True
        else:
           return "This is where I'm returning with 50, and True as my parameters"
    elif temp >= 90: 
        return False
    elif temp <= 60:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug it?
With `squirrel_play(50, False)` it will fall into:

```
def squirrel_play(temp, is_summer):

if is_summer:
    if temp <= 100:
        if temp >= 60:
            return True
    elif temp <= 60:
        return False
    elif temp >= 100:
        return False
if not is_summer:
    if temp <= 90:
        if temp >= 60:
            return True
        # HERE ( 50 is less than 90 but not greater than 60 ) 
        # and you have no return statement for this case
    elif temp >= 90: 
        return False
    elif temp <= 60:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that you have currently coded it, in your

```
    if temp <= 90:
        if temp >= 60:
            return True
    elif ....
```

if the first `if` test evaluates True but the second one evaluates False, then no `return` statement is reached (bear in mind that the subsequent `elif` tests are not performed because the first `if` evaluated true), and the function therefore returns `None`.

In fact you can simplify the function making use of [chained comparison operators](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/):

```
def squirrel_play(temp, is_summer):
    if is_summer:
        return 60 <= temp <= 100
    else:
        return 60 <= temp <= 90
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't return a value from a Python function, `None` is returned by default. I believe that what is happening here is that because you are using `elif` statements, since the clause `if not is_summer: if temp <= 90:` is being entered, the final clause `elif temp <= 60` is not being reached. Therefore the function gets passed all of the `if`/`elif` statements without returning a value, and returns `None`.

A simple solution is to replace all of the `elif`s with `if`s. Then `print(squirrel_play(50, False))` returns `False` (for me at least).